# Not able to create a new site through wizard option available in Web 8 CME

Tags: web8

I am trying to create a new site through "Create new site" option available in sites menu in content manager explorer. It is showing "No Data" for "Site Type". Can anyone suggest where to set "Site Type". I can see steps to create a new site through wizard at sdl docs url(http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-1E52F7BA-ADFA-4BAB-AD7E-65104EE29B6B#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-1E52F7BA-ADFA-4BAB-AD7E-65104EE29B6B.xml&docid=GUID-1E52F7BA-ADFA-4BAB-AD7E-65104EE29B6B&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-1E52F7BA-ADFA-4BAB-AD7E-65104EE29B6B). Am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea behind Site Wizard (the "Create new site" option) is to make creation of a new Site/Publication very simple.

Unfortunately, to make this possible you will first have to do some more complex configuration:

1. Create a parent Publication containing the design items and set its Publication Type to "Site Type". Also put a clear (symbolic) name in its Key property.
2. Optionally, create a parent Publication containing the (master) content items and set its Publication Type to "Content"
3. Ensure you have Topology Manager configured with Topology Type, Topology, CD Environment(s), Website(s) and Web Application(s).
4. Use the `Add-TTmSiteTypeKey` cmdlet to assign the Publication Key from step 1 to the appropriate Web Application(s) and Topology.

Only when all those step have been done will you be able to select a Site Type in the Site Wizard.

Note that DXA 1.3 will come with pre-defined Site Type(s) and PowerShell scripts to configure Topology Manager accordingly.

For now, you're on your own. :-)