# Adding a SiteType / Selecting a Site Type in the wizard

Tags: web8, topology-manager, site-types

I've the same issue as described in this question :

[Not able to create a new site through wizard option available in Web 8 CME](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13655/not-able-to-create-a-new-site-through-wizard-option-available-in-web-8-cme)

and I've gone through the step's in Rick's answer (thanks rick!) but i'm still unable to select a site type, none exist in the CME when working thought the steps in the wizard.

When I look at my sites, I see that I know have a ScopedRepositoryKeys value

```
> BaseUrls             : {http://staging.dxa.com} CdEnvironmentId      :
> CdEnvironment2 EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging CdEnvironment        : 
> ScopedRepositoryKeys : {DxaSiteType}
> Id                   : Website2
> ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

I've ran the following powershell scripts:

- Get-TtmCdTopology
- Get-TtmCdEnvironment
- Get-TtmWebsite
- Get-TtmWebApplication

And I see the ScopedRepository Key in all results,  what else am i missing?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you set the Site Type Publication and key?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to configure a DXA site?  Note that DXA 1.3 comes with OOTB support for Site Types and Site Wizard: it includes a PowerShell Script to configure Topology Manager and the OOTB Publications have been configured to act as Site Type or Content Publication.

Comment: @AlvinReyes yes i did

Comment: @RickPannekoek - yes, but i still need to know what i've missed doing this manually

Comment: The Scoped Repository Keys should be a list of Publication _keys_, to match the keys in Publication properties.