# What does `Add-TTmSiteTypeKey` do and can we do something similar?

Tags: configuration, topology-manager

As mentioned in [this answer on the SiteWizard](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/13656/46) and [described in SDL Docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-87A938C3-249A-42DD-AD6D-45CC4BDA41DD), you use `Add-TtmSiteTypeKey` to configure a Publication to be a Site Type.

Where is this configuration stored in Topology Manager (i.e. with which entity: Topology, Web Application, etc.)?

And is this mechanism public? In other words, can implementers also store per-environment settings in Topology Manager in some type of *extended data*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add-TtmSiteTypeKey` does not configure a Publication to be a Site Type (you do that by setting the Publication's Publication Type to "Site Type"), but it associates a Site Type (Publication), with Web Application(s) in Topology Manager.

This is done to be able to infer Publication Mappings from the Site Type (if you use the Site Wizard).

The "Site Type Key" (i.e. the Key of the Publication/Repository acting as Site Type) is stored as `ScopedRepositoryKeys` property on several entities in Topology Manager: WebApplication, Website, CdEnvironment, CdTopology.

This mechanism is not intended to be extensible, but Topology Manager does provide an `ExtensionProperties` property on all entities, which is intended as general purpose extension point; it allows you to add key/value pairs to each entity. `ExtensionProperties` on WebApplication and Mapping entities are also pushed to Discovery Service (which also has such extension properties).

Comment: Perfect. And is there a specific format for `ExtensionProperties` (e.g. JSON, meaning we could put _any_ type of configuration)?

Comment: It is a Dictionary with String keys and String values.  Neither have meaning for Topology Manager  itself, so you could indeed store JSON (or XML or YAML) in the value.